# Debugging Excel Office Add-in with Visual Studio now requires Administrator mode

Tags: visual-studio, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

We can no longer run our Excel Add-ins in debug mode.

This can be replicated by creating a new project in Visual Studio from the template: "Excel Web Add-in". When the solution is run, the Add-in does not load, there is a loading spinner in the Task Pane:

[image]

This was working fine until the last week or two so perhaps a Windows or Visual Studio update has caused this?

If Visual Studio is launched in Administrator mode then the Add-in runs as expected and the Task Pane loads. In addition, saving to local storage seems to not work when Visual Studio is in Admin mode.

Has anybody else experienced this and if so is there a solution? Thanks.

Comment: I can reproduce this. It's either a bug in VS or a bug in Office. I think you should create an issue in the [office.js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) repo. Be sure to provide the full version numbers for VS and Office.

Comment: Thanks. There is already an issue in the repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3889 I will add a comment with the version numbers, hopefully that will help with the investigation/fix.

Comment: Seems to be something that came in with 17.8.3 as someone on my team is seeing the issue on two different machines when working on a Word Add-in.  I'm not seeing it but I've not upgraded (still on 17.7.4) and won't upgraded until we see a resolution to this.

Comment: It seems like you can rollback Visual Studio to the previous version, which in my case will be to 17.8.1 (currently on 17.8.3). I'll try this and report back here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-visual-studio-rollback/

Comment: I'm reproducing it on 17.7.7, so I don't think it's the VS version. This problem is being looked at in Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my support. Spent all last week on this.
I eventually setup a clean VM to test.

- Win 11 VM
- VS 2022 Community 17.8.3.
- Office 365 build 17023.20068.

Created a new Word Web add-in and Excel Web add-in projects. Same result, F5 debugging the task pane is blank, DevTools shows no reply from localhost.
Run VS as Admin - works.